# Creating nested links in Django template from a list of objects

Tags: django-templates

I'm new to Django, so apologies in advance if this is a rookie issue.

Basically, I am passing a list of objects ('tags') to a template and would like to create the following display:

**tag1**> **tag2**> **tag3**

where

- tag1 is a link to
  /mysite.com/tag1
- tag2 is a link
  to /mysite.com/tag1/tag2
- tag3 is a link to
  http://mysite.com/tag1/tag2/tag3

I cannot for the life of me figure out how to create the three links, for any given list of 'tags' objects passed to the template, since the obvious solution of a path_string variable that gets updated with every *for* loop pass cannot work, because variables cannot be declared/ modified in Django templates.

I looked up some advanced templates topics, and tried messing with filters etc. but didn't make any headway. Any suggestions?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

These are called breadcrumbs. Try this [How to implement breadcrumbs in a Django template?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/826889/how-to-implement-breadcrumbs-in-a-django-template) or this http://code.google.com/p/django-breadcrumbs/ or this http://www.martin-geber.com/thought/2007/10/25/breadcrumbs-django-templates/

Comment: Seems to be exactly what I was looking for. Thanks Matt! Onward to implementation...