# Breadcrumbs in Django

Tags: django

Sorry for repeatition of such a nontrivial question. I have a structure of my website similar to:
- flatpages ( one-level nesting[1] )
- gallery ( '/gallery' for album list and '/gallery/album/id/' for any album, 'gallery/picture/id' for any picture )
- price-list ( similar to gallery )
- guestbook ( similar to flatpage in 'breadcrumbing' )

The question is: do I have to write my own breadcrumbs and parse url for every application separately? maybe there are some unique breadcrumbs applications?

ps: I can't install anything to 'python/site-packages' because of my hoster circs..

[1] I don't know how to tell this word in English :) sorry if I mistaken

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There are a lot of ready to go applications out there ie. https://github.com/chronossc/django-breadcrumbs

The best approach in your hosting case would be to install your site in a virtual environment (it's probably installed by default on your server, http://tumblr.intranation.com/post/766290325/python-virtualenv-quickstart-django). If this is not possible then simply unpack breadcrumbs application of your choice to your main application folder and add it to your settings as a local app (vide `INSTALLED_APPS`).

You can also implement it yourself - [How to implement breadcrumbs in a Django template?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/826889/how-to-implement-breadcrumbs-in-a-django-template).