# Extending breadcrumbs with block.super in django using DRY priniples

Tags: django, templates

I am having trouble implementing django_breadcrumbs in a DRY fashion using block.super.

I have a template "editions" that the user can reach in one of two ways: either from home, in which case the user sees all the editions, or from the template "surveys", in which case the user sees only the editions for that survey.
The breadcrumbs for the editions template look like this and they work fine:

```
{% extends 'base.html' %}
{% load django_bootstrap_breadcrumbs %}
{% block breadcrumbs %}
    {{ block.super }}
    {% if slug %}
        {% breadcrumb "Surveys" "surveys:index" %}
        {% breadcrumb "Editions" "editions:index" slug=slug %}
    {% else %}
        {% breadcrumb "Editions" "editions:index" %}
    {% endif %}
{% endblock %}
```

Disappoinment ensues for pages that hang off the editions template. I had hoped that by extending that page and using block.super, I would inherit the proper breadcrumbs depending on where the edition came from. But I only ever get the Editions breadcrumb even when I hoped for the Surveys / Editions breadcrumbs.
Here is the template "create" which hangs off "edition":

```
{% extends 'editions/index.html' %}
{% load bootstrap3 %}
{% load django_bootstrap_breadcrumbs %}
{% block breadcrumbs %}
    {{ block.super }}
    {% breadcrumb "Create" "editions:create" %}
{% endblock %}
```

I could always put another if: else: in that template, but I would rather just inherit the if: else: from the previous template. What is it I don't understand? Do I need to pass the slug back up to the super:block or something? How would I do that without repeating the same if: else: in the child template? Indeed, how would I do that at even with a new if: else:?

thanks

John

Answer (score 0, accepted):

My best guess is that you render the second template without passing the `slug` variable. Your inheritance is correct, but as the parent (or super) template uses the `slug` variable, what it renders depends on the variable's contents. Therefore, if no variable called `slug` is passed, you will always get the else-part of your if statement.

So, the solution seems quite simple: add the `slug` variable to the context parameter when triggering the template render.