# How to get the current URL linkable within a Django template?

Tags: python, django

Lets say my url is:

```
/userpanel/send/sms
```

I want to make option for user to get back to `/userpanel/` once somebody click on 
/**userpanel**/send/sms . Or to `userpanel/send/` once somebody click on userpanel/**send**/sms

Is there a way to get all the possible separable urls?

Im using

```
{{ request.get_full_path }}
```

But seems useless to archive my goal.

> EDIT: I meant breadcrumps, and i found there are no built in
>   breadcrumps in django.

Comment: Can you explain more you want to get back to userpanel once the same user click on sendsms ?
Right

Comment: I think what you are looking for is breadcrumbs, see this question https://stackoverflow.com/questions/826889/how-to-implement-breadcrumbs-in-a-django-template

Comment: Possible duplicate of [this one](https://stackoverflow.com/q/826889/1165509)